# Amend perl script so that words are matched on a word for word basis

Tags: text-processing, perl

I have been using this perl script (thanks to Jeff Schaller) to match 3 or more words in the title fields of two separate csv files. 
Original question here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283942/matching-3-or-more-words-from-fields-in-separate-csv-files?noredirect=1#comment494461_283942

I have also added some exception functionality following advice from meuh:

```
#!/bin/perl

my @csv2 = ();
open CSV2, "<csv2" or die;
@csv2=<CSV2>;
close CSV2;

my %csv2hash = ();
for (@csv2) {
  chomp;
  my ($title) = $_ =~ /^.+?,\s*([^,]+?),/; #/ match the title 
  $csv2hash{$_} = $title;
}

open CSV1, "<csv1" or die;
while (<CSV1>) {
  chomp;
  my ($title) = $_ =~ /^.+?,\s*([^,]+?),/; #/ match the title 
  my @titlewords = split /\s+/, $title;    #/ get words

  my @new;                          #add exception words which shouldn't be matched
  foreach my $t (@titlewords){
  push(@new, $t) if $t !~ /^(and|if|where)$/i;
  }
  @titlewords = @new;
  my $desired = 3;
  my $matched = 0;
  foreach my $csv2 (keys %csv2hash) {
    my $count = 0;
    my $value = $csv2hash{$csv2};
    foreach my $word (@titlewords) {
      ++$count if $value =~ /\b$word\b/i;
      last if $count >= $desired;
    }
    if ($count >= $desired) {
      print "$csv2\n";
      ++$matched;
    }
  }
  print "$_\n" if $matched;
}
close CSV1;
```

During my testing, one issue I've found that I would like to tweak is that if csv2 contains a single common word such as `the`, if this is replicated in csv1 three or more times then three positive matches is found. To clarify:

If csv1 contains:

```
1216454,the important people feel the same way as the others, 15445454, 45445645
```

^ i.e. there are three insatnces of `the` in the above line

If csv2 contains:

```
14564564,the tallest man on earth,546456,47878787
```

^ i.e. there is one instance of `the` in this line

Then I would like only one word to be classed as matching, and there be no output (based on my desired number of matching words- 3 ) because there is only one instance of the matching word in one of the files.

However if:

csv1 contained:

```
1216454,the important people feel the same way as the others,15445454, 45445645
```

and csv2 contained:

```
15456456,the only way the man can sing the blues,444545,454545
```

Then, as there are three matching words in each (i.e. 3 instances of the word `the` in each title, then I would like this to be classed as a matching title based on my desired number of matching words being 3 or more, thus generating the output:

```
1216454,the important people feel the same way as the others,15445454, 45445645
15456456,the only way the man can sing the blues,444545,454545
```

I would like to amend the script so that if there is one instance of a word in a csv, and multiple instances of the same word in the other csv then that is classed as only one match. However, if there were say 3 instance of the word `the` in both files, then it should still be classed as three matches. Basically I would like matches to be on a word for word basis. 
Everything about the script other than this is perfect so I would rather not go back to the drawing board completely as I am happy with everything other than this. 
I hope I've explained it ok, if anyone need any clarification let me know.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us an example of the input you need to parse and the output you would like to see. A link to your previous question for context would also be helpful. I think what you want is to count only unique matches, ignoring repetitions of the same word. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wan to count unique matches, you can use a hash instead of a list to collect the words from `csv1`, just like you do for `csv2`, and then also count the occurrences of each word separately:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my @csv2 = ();
open CSV2, "<csv2" or die;
@csv2=<CSV2>;
close CSV2;

my %csv2hash = ();
for (@csv2) {
  chomp;
  my ($title) = $_ =~ /^.+?,\s*([^,]+?),/; #/ match the title 
  $csv2hash{$_} = $title;
}

open CSV1, "<csv1" or die;
while (<CSV1>) {
  chomp;
  my ($title) = $_ =~ /^.+?,\s*([^,]+?),/; #/ match the title 
    my %words;
    $words{$_}++ for split /\s+/, $title;    #/ get words
    ## Collect unique words
    my @titlewords = keys(%words);
  my @new;                          #add exception words which shouldn't be matched
  foreach my $t (@titlewords){
        push(@new, $t) if $t !~ /^(and|if|where)$/i;
  }
  @titlewords = @new;
  my $desired = 3;
  my $matched = 0;
  foreach my $csv2 (keys %csv2hash) {
    my $count = 0;
    my $value = $csv2hash{$csv2};
    foreach my $word (@titlewords) {
            my @matches   = ( $value=~/\b$word\b/ig );
            my $numIncsv2 = scalar(@matches);
            @matches      = ( $title=~/\b$word\b/ig );
            my $numIncsv1 = scalar(@matches);
            ++$count if $value =~ /\b$word\b/i;
            if ($count >= $desired || ($numIncsv1 >= $desired && $numIncsv2 >= $desired)) {
                $count = $desired+1;
                last;
            }
    }
    if ($count >= $desired) {
      print "$csv2\n";
      ++$matched;
    }
  }
  print "$_\n" if $matched;
}
close CSV1;
```

Comment: Hi terdon, this is closer to what I want to achieve definitely, however see my edit to my question with sample output. At the moment your amendment will only match 1 instance of the a given word then move on, but if both files contain multiple instances of the same word I would like them to count as matches.

Comment: @nmh OK, see updated script. Next time though, make sure to include enough examples for us to understand. Show us sample data that reproduce all possible situations and explain what output you need from it. Also, this sort of complex question is really not good for the site. If the answer to your question is a full script, then you need to break the question into smaller chunks that you can use to write the script yourself.

Comment: Ok, understood. My original question did start with me trying to use grep but then morphed into a perl script which I know very little about! Thanks for your help, I'll try and split my queries up in the future.

Comment: Hi terdon, I've been reading this script quite regularly and I don''t know if it's just me, but I struggle to read perl, even if I break it down. I was wondering if you could add some additional # comments to the answer just so I can get my head around how it works?